# Integer multiplication algorithm using a divide and conquer approach?

Tags: algorithm, biginteger, divide-and-conquer

As homework, I should implement integer multiplication on numbers of a 1000 digits using a divide and conquer approach that works below O(n). What algorithm should I look into?

Comment: The time complexity can't be less than O(n) if n is the size of the input. Then you wouldn't even be able to read the entire input.

Comment: I suspect the _O(n)_ is referring to pseudo-polynomial time, i.e. he actually wants something better than _O(2^n)_. Many simple algorithms will satisfy this requirement, but you might get extra credit for implementing one of the ones in the answers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mistake it for O(n * n) ? If then, you have 1) Karatsuba's algorithm which runs in O(n^(log3 / log2)) and 2) FFT methods in O(n log n) (technically it is O(n * log^* n)). Simplest to code is Karatsuba.

Comment: It's a mistake on the problem statement. I already emailed my teacher, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage-Strassen_algorithm) is the one of the fastest multiplication algorithms known. It takes O(n log n log log n)  time.

[Fürer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm) is the fastest large number multiplication algorithm known so far and takes  O(n*log n * 2<sup>O(log*n)</sup>) time.

I don't think any multiplication algorithm could take less than or even equal to O(n). That's simply not possible.

Comment: cool ! back in 2003 that was one student's project of mine. I implemented Karatsuba and FFT over the reals (not Schönhage, this one is O(n log^* n) ), which is far easier to get working when you don't master algebra. Glad to see there is something new in the field. By the way you mixed the two complexities. Schonhage Strassen is the O(n log n log log n) one. Also, Fürer is not exactly O(n log n), it is O(n log n 2^(log^* n)), according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Algorithm). It involves a recursion step which you can easily model with divide-and-conquer.